# Creating a class instance as a default argument inside itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, init

I've made a function inside a class with an argument I want that argument to default to becoming an instance of the class if not specified.

here's what I assumed would work:

```py
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, value = dict):
        self.value = value

    def arbitrary(self, other_instance = self.__class__({})):
        print(other_instance.value.get('placeholder', 0))
```

However, it claims self is not defined. Theoretically, I could simply just do

```
    def arbitrary(self, other_instance = None):
        if other_instance is None:
            other_instance = self.__class__({})
        print(other_instance.value.get('placeholder', 0))
```

however that's pretty cobbled together, so I wanted to know if there was a way to do it within the argument default before I resort to something like that.

Comment: The approach with `None` is a standard approach. `self` is not defined at the point when the method is being defined; it is passed in when the method is called.

Comment: No, this is the reasonable way to do it. You cannot reference the class inside of a class definition statement. You *could* do this by defining the function *after* the class definition staetment then doing something like `Agent.arbitrary = arbitrary`, but note, you wouldn't be able to reference `self` because `self` is a *paramter*

Comment: `arbitrary` should probably be a class method; you are aren't using `self` except to get its type, and that type is what will be passed as the first argument when a class method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a better solution to your actual problem, but since you're not sharing those details, it's hard to say what exactly.

However, for the example you're giving, in case `other_instance` would be `None`, `value` would be an empty `dict`, and thus the call to `.get()` can only return `0`.

So, this is equivalent:

```
    def arbitrary(self, other_instance = None):
        if other_instance is None:
            print(0)
        else:
            print(other_instance.value.get('placeholder', 0))
```

Which avoids the construction of a throwaway instance altogether.

Your actual use case may have a bit more going on, but it's likely there's a better solution than on-the-fly creation of an empty instance as well. If there's not, the solution you have with `None` is the expected way to do it.

(Note: setting `value` to `dict` in the constructor in the first example actually sets it to the *type*, not an empty instance, which is probably what you intended - however, doing so would cause warnings about a mutable default, and the correct solution there is to use `None` and initialisation in the body as well)

Edit: in the comments you indicated that you set `value` to `dict` to signal what type is needed - however, this has the unwanted side effect that some IDEs will infer that the type of `value` is `type` or `Any`, which it isn't. Instead, use this:

```
from typing import Optional


class ClassName:
    def arbitrary(self, other_instance: Optional[dict] = None):
        if other_instance is None:
            print(0)
        else:
            print(other_instance.value.get('placeholder', 0))
```

Comment: yeah, setting `value` to `dict` was intentional. Granted, it's not very useful since it would break my program to not input `value` regardless, more just a reminder for me of what argument needs what data type. I'm using VScode, so it'll pop up while i'm calling a func. Saves some time.

Comment: Use a type hint instead: `def __init__(self, value: Optional[dict] = None):` instead of `def __init__(self, value = dict):` - IDEs support this as well, and is a formal part of Python. The only downside being you'll need the `Optional` from `typing`. You can leave it off and go `def __init__(self, value: dict = None):`, but this will generate a warning that `None` isn't a `dict` (and it isn't), that's what the `Optional` fixes. And it *is* optional, in that your constructor works just fine without one. In, `value = dict` signals that the type of `value` is `type`, which it isn't.